# HTML parsing - fetch and update data from the .html file

Tags: html, regex, grails, groovy

I have a form in a .html files where input/select box looks like this

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" value="##myName##" />

<select id="cbGender"  name="cbGender">
 <option>Select</option>
 <option selected="selected">Male</option>
 <option>Female</option>
</select>
```

I would need to remove '##' value textbox and also update them with different values if needed be in the textbox/checkbox/ selectbox. I would know the id of the input types. The code is to be written in groovy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me (took a bit of trial and error)

```
@Grab(group='org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup', module='tagsoup', version='1.2')
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.*
import groovy.xml.*

String htmlTxt = """<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" value="##myName##" />
    <select id="cbGender"  name="cbGender">
       <option>Select</option>
       <option selected="selected">Male</option>
       <option>Female</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>"""

// Define our TagSoup backed parser
def slurper = new XmlSlurper( new Parser() )

// Parse our html
def h = slurper.parseText( htmlTxt )

// Find the input with the id 'txtName'
def i = h.body.input.list().find { it.@id == 'txtName' }

// Change it's value
i.@value = 'new value'

// Write it out (into a StringWriter for now)
def w = new StringWriter()
w << new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  // Required to avoid the html: namespace on every node
  mkp.declareNamespace '':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
  mkp.yield h
}
// XmlUtil.serialize neatens up our resultant xml -- but adds an xml declaration :-(
println new XmlUtil().serialize( w.toString() )
```

**[edit]**

That gives this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <input id="txtName" name="txtName" value="new value" type="text"/>
    <select id="cbGender" name="cbGender">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option selected="selected">Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Groovy's XmlParser supports reading and updating of XML documents.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the builtin groovy builder. It can work also with a custom **SAX** parser like [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/).

You can easily do things like

```
tbl.tr.list().each { row ->

}
```

as described [here](http://froth-and-java.blogspot.com/2007/06/html-screen-scraping-with-groovy.html)..